# dynamic finder behavior has changed in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'am migrating an application from Grails 2.5 to Grails 3.1.10, i've encountered a problem with dynamic finder : findAllByXXInList

In Grails 2.5 even if an empty list is passed as argument, there is no SQLException, it returns just empty list as result.

```
findAllByXXInList([]) // no exception with Grails 2.5
```

But in Grails 3, it throws an exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
```

if un empty list is passed as argument.
Is this a change in Gorm 5 ?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need to pass en empty list to a dynamic finder?

Comment: See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8091 & https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9352